# How to prepopulate in Strapi Service - V4

Tags: strapi

I'm looking to prepopulate my endpoints with related data and perform transformation but i'm unsure i've approach this most effectively. I feel like somehow the additional query(s) within the find(...args) being looped is adding to the request and thus hitting performance.

Any advise is much appreciated on how i can perhaps populate in the initial find.

```
'use strict';

const baseTransformer = require('../../../utils/base-transformer');
const { formatDate, formatTime } = require('../../../utils/datetime');
const { getProperty } = require('../../../utils/props');

/**
 * article service
 */

const { createCoreService } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreService('api::article.article', ({ strapi }) => ({
  async find(...args) {
    const { results, pagination } = await super.find(...args);

    const formattedArticles = [];
    for (const result of results) {
      const nextArticleIndex = results.indexOf(result) + 1;
      const nextArticle =
        nextArticleIndex < results.length ? results[nextArticleIndex] : null;

      const populatedResult = await strapi
        .query('api::article.article')
        .findOne({
          where: { id: result.id },
          populate: { tags: true, primary_image: true },
        });

      formattedArticles.push({
        ...baseTransformer(result, 'article'),
        date: formatDate(result.publishedAt),
        time: formatTime(result.publishedAt),
        primary_image: getProperty(populatedResult, 'primary_image', {}),
        article_tags: getProperty(populatedResult, 'tags', []),
        nextArticle,
      });
    }

    const articlesWithNext = formattedArticles.map((result, index) => {
      const nextArticleIndex = index + 1;
      const nextArticle =
        nextArticleIndex < results.length ? results[nextArticleIndex] : null;

      return {
        ...result,
        nextArticle,
      };
    });

    return { results: articlesWithNext, pagination };
  },
  async findOne(...args) {
    const result = await super.findOne(...args);

    return result;
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well basically `args` object (that is normally called `ctx` in koa and so in strapi) contains `query` key, witch includes populate, so you can pretty much add your default populate directly to it:

```js
const defaultFindArgs = {
  populate: {
    …
  }
}

async find(ctx) {
   const quey = {
        …ctx.query,
        …defaultFindArgs
       };

   const data = await super.find({…ctx, query})
}
```

P.s. about recommendations, it’s generally recommended to do that type of stuff in middleware (pre populate, transform). E.g. write once use anywhere. But it’s bit more tricky…